# ng-if an element has a certain class

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

I was wondering if it is possible to have an ng-if be true if an element has a certain class.

Example:

```
<div class="edge" ng-repeat="item in items">
<div ui-view ng-if="(ng-repeat div has class of edge)"
```

Comment: How do you add the class on this `div`?

Comment: Currently I use JS to tell if element is in same row as others and add the class if the element is the last one of same height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Practically you can use `hasClass` method with angular element:

```
angular.element(myElement).hasClass('my-class');
```

So you can create a function and put the check in it and use that function in `ng-if`.

```
<div class="edge" ng-if="check()" ng-repeat="item in items">
```

However, remember that you cannot access the element in `ng-if` (vs you can pass the `$event` to `ng-click` and access `$event.target`) , need to create a directive to do it.

Comment: Thanks, @YaserAdelMehraban. I seem to he having trouble with the function. I know I am doing something wrong :/ 
```$scope.check = function(){
         if (angular.element.hasClass('edge')) {  
         }
         
     };
```

Comment: I think I understand what I am not understanding. You see, I am looking to have the ng-if = true only on a list item with a certain class as opposed to open if an element has a class. When I implemented your suggestion, because one of the li had the class it equaled true and opened under ALL of them. You answer did technically answer my question so I will mark it as answer.

Comment: Glad it helped @JediCoder